# how to add space to the string in bash, and make it look like a table output?

Tags: bash, shell, printf

data:

```
place|place_loc|CATA|CATB|CATA1|CATB1
AAAAA|AAAAA_AAA|1234|123|12|1234
```

expected output:

```
place_loc| AAAAA_AAA
|CATA: 1234   CATA1:12
|CATB: 123    CATB1:1234
```

Current bash script:

```
cat info.txt | tr '\t' '|' | tail -n+2 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"} {
{printf "place_loc|%11s\n",$2}
{if ($2!="#N/A" && $2!="")
{printf "|CATA:%6s         CATA1:%7s\n",$3,$5}
{printf "|CATB:%6s          CATB1:%12s\n",$4,$6}
}'
```

Since the input need to concern the string length from 1-10, like CATA: 0123456789, but once i add a longer string for CATA, CATA1 will move backward.

Or can I awk the info.txt to make it looks like:
place|place_loc|CATA|CATB|CATA1|CATB1
AAAAA|AAAAA_AAA|1234     |123       |12        |1234
edit the input file add $3,$4,$5,$6 space until reach length=10

Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts in your question(keep it up), could you please do mention logic of getting expected output more clearly, sorry its not much clear as of now, thank you.

Comment: expected output are getting from a csv (sperated by "|", likes the info.txt). So i am try to "cat" the info.txt out and print it as a table by awk. But the data in CATA,CATA1,CATB,CATB1 are not in the same length, it makes my current bash script output table format looks bad.

Comment: @Noktang : The tricky part is that you know the size of your field only after you have the length of all strings involved. Hence I would first process the file and store all the bits you want to output into some variables, then calculate the length of the respective fields and store this into variables too, and from this generate the output using `printf`, but now using your length variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can all be done in `awk` with two rules. You can handle outputting the first part of the heading in the second rule, saving all fields in the array `a[]`, and then the second rule will output the needed elements of `a[]` and the current fields in the format you specify. For example:

Set `'|'` as the field separator wtih `-F'|'`, and

```
awk -F'|' '
    FNR > 1 {                                           # record (line) > 1
        if (FNR == 2)                                   # if line is 2
            print "| " $2                               # finish heading row
        for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=2)                            # loop from 3rd field by 2
            printf (i==3?"|":"\t") "%s: %s ",a[i],$i    # output info
        for (i=4;i<=NF;i+=2)                            # loop from 4th field by 2
            printf (i==4?"\n|":"\t") "%s: %s ",a[i],$i  # output info
        print ""                                        # tidy up with newline
        delete a                                        # clear the array
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)                           # fill array with current fields
            a[i]=$i
        next                                            # skip to next line
    }
    {
        printf "%s", $2                                 # output 1st part of heading
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)                           # fill array with current fields
            a[i]=$i
    }
' file
```

The order of execution is a bit backwards. The rule handling the first line is actually the last rule above between the bottom `{...}` the top rule handles the second line on.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in the file named `file`, you can just select-copy the above and middle-mouse paste into an xterm with the current directory containing `file` to test, e.g.:

```
awk -F'|' '
>     FNR > 1 {                                           # record (line) > 1
>         if (FNR == 2)                                   # if line is 2
>             print "| " $2                               # finish heading row
>         for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=2)                            # loop from 3rd field by 2
>             printf (i==3?"|":"\t") "%s: %s ",a[i],$i    # output info
>         for (i=4;i<=NF;i+=2)                            # loop from 4th field by 2
>             printf (i==4?"\n|":"\t") "%s: %s ",a[i],$i  # output info
>         print ""                                        # tidy up with newline
>         delete a                                        # clear the array
>         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)                           # fill array with current fields
>             a[i]=$i
>         next                                            # skip to next line
>     }
>     {
>         printf "%s", $2                                 # output 1st part of heading
>         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)                           # fill array with current fields
>             a[i]=$i
>     }
> ' file
place_loc| AAAAA_AAA
|CATA: 1234     CATA1: 12
|CATB: 123      CATB1: 1234
```

The output above is:

```
place_loc| AAAAA_AAA
|CATA: 1234     CATA1: 12
|CATB: 123      CATB1: 1234
```